# Knowing the service that opens the port

Tags: debian, systemd, nmap

I want to close unnecessary ports in debian 8.2.

```
$ nmap localhost | grep open
25/tcp  open  smtp
631/tcp open  ipp
```

Searching the service that corresponds to smtp,

```
$ lsof -i:25
$ sudo systemctl --all | grep smtp
```

Nothing shows up on both commands.
The same for ipp.
I couldn't know the service that opens the port.
What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

The `lsof` command has to be run as root, otherwise it will only show listened-on ports belonging to your user.

```
# lsof -i:25
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
master  844 root   12u  IPv4   6975      0t0  TCP *:smtp (LISTEN)
master  844 root   13u  IPv6   6976      0t0  TCP *:smtp (LISTEN)
```

The `systemctl` command only knows about services, not port numbers or protocol names.  i.e. you need to know which particular package (e.g. `sendmail`, `exim`, `postfix`, etc) is providing the smtp service.  e.g.

```
# systemctl | grep -E 'postfix|exim|sendmail|qmail'
postfix.service
```

another option is to be a bit more generic in what you're searching for.  e.g. grep for `mail` rather than `smtp`

```
# systemctl --all | grep -i mail
  postfix.service                 loaded    active   running   LSB: Postfix Mail Transport Agent
  mail-transport-agent.target     loaded    active   active    Mail Transport Agent
```

Comment: another option is the "p" flag to netstat -- shows the PID that opened the port; can then backtrack to get the process name and related service

Comment: true, but `netstat -tpan | grep :25` doesn't tell you anything more than what `lsof -i:25` does.

Comment: Yep -- just in case lsof isn't available. Wanted to put all the options together instead of having a separate answer.

Comment: @cas - `$ sudo systemctl --all | grep "postfix\|exim\|sendmail\|qmail"  \n  
  exim4.service`
I stopped this service.
`$ sudo lsof -i:631  \n  
cupsd   720 root   10u  IPv6  15065      0t0  TCP localhost:ipp (LISTEN)`
To leave printing available,I don't want to stop cupsd.
This port isn't opened to the the outside world.Is that right? If so, no need to kill cupsd.

Comment: `localhost:ipp` says it's only listening on the loopback interface for the ipp port, i.e. not accessible outside the host itself.